# Facebook Php Api basics

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

Im getting started with the php sdk, and struggling to understand a few things (I have a basic example below - but everytime the pic goes to MY wall and not the fan page)

Code:

```
    require_once("facebook.php"); // set the right path

    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = 'app id';
    $config['secret'] = 'app secret';
    $config['fileUpload'] = true; // optional
    $fb = new Facebook($config);

    $params = array(
      // this is the access token for Fan Page
      "access_token" => "I create this via the graph api (select App and click get token), I select publish stream and photo_upload permissions.",
      "message" => "test message",
      "source" => "@" ."photo.png", // "@" . 
    );

    try {
      // **** is Facebook id of Fan page 
      $ret = $fb->api('/****/photos', 'POST', $params);
      echo 'Photo successfully uploaded to Facebook Album';
    } catch(Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

the picture keeps going to MY wall (logged in user) and not the fan page, is that because im getting a token for the currently logged in user (me) instead of the fan page? and if so how do i generate a token for the fan page whilst logged in as the developer? (is it by putting the fan page id into the Get bar?)

Apologies for the noob questions but the facebook documentation sucks (until u understand the core functionality of course). Most tutorials work once u know how to use the graph API - none ive looked actually EXPLAIN how to use the graph to generate correct tokens, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`\POST /<ID>/photos` — this will post on the `<ID>`'s wall only, so please double-check the `<ID>` that you are using.

The access token will depict that on behalf of whom the photo would be posted on the `<ID>`'s wall. If you use the **user access token**, the photo will be published on behalf of the user and if **page access token** is used, it will be published on the page's behalf itself.

You can get the page access token of your pages by-

```
\GET  /me/accounts?fields=access_token
```

(permission required: `manage_pages`)

[Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts%3Ffields%3Daccess_token)

Comment: Every time i run this i get "successfully uploaded" - so im sure the token/id/secret is correct.

I use the graph, select the app, and click "get access token" - (does it matter what id is in the GET bar?) I make sure publish_stream, photo_upload is checked.

When i debug this token, its always granted to ME? why is this, isnt this granting permissions to anyone who uses this app? all it seems to do is apply permissions to ME the developer! every time i run the app it posts to MY(developer) wall and NOT the fan page (as ME) - even though i specify the fan page id in the PATH. Please help!!

Comment: "isnt this granting permissions to anyone who uses this app" - are you really serious? How in the world can you get the access token of any user (other than you). Please refine your concepts. Obviously you can get the access token for your ownself. Can you get the facebook password of mine? - this is similar to that. another thing, did you post like this: `/page-id/photos` OR `/me/photos`? `me` will post to your wall and `page-id` to your page. This concept is very simple and very clear.